# File is not writable in redhat linux while running opencart

Tags: linux, azure, opencart, file-permissions

I am trying to migrate my local **open-cart** application to Linux Red Hat 7.2 virtual machine server on Azure. I have set the permission for the webserver 'apache' using the following command

```
chown apache:apache /var/www/html/
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/
```

[image]

as you can see apache has the read/write/execute permissions. but when i try to run the site it throws me the following error

[image]

I don't know what am I doing wrong here. I have checked the permission on every folder. I have also echoed

`echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user();
echo '<br>Current script owner: '. exec('whoami');`

First one gives me *user-omgchicks* and second one *apache*. I am a little confused here, who is accessing the files and how can i set the same permission for both the users?

Comment: A screenshot of the listing of the particular files throwing the errors (e.g. `/var/www/html/system/library/log.php`) would be better...

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED ANSWER**
Finally this solved it for me.

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/
```

Everything works perfect now. But I don't know how vulnerable have I made the server by doing this ?